# Detect if was redirected from specific urls or domains

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Like If i'm on a url like this: "http://specificdomain.com/path/".
and i clicked on a button on that page with a code like this:

```
<a href="http://afterclicked.url/path/">Go!!!</a>
```

How can i detect if i was redirect from that domain or that url (http://specificdomain.com/path/) but not any else/not directed open.
edit: and the "afterclicked.url" is my website, so that is the place that have the code to detect.

Comment: Read about `document.referrer`

Comment: You can use the [`REFERER` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) but it's not reliable and is under user control (a browser user can disable it in some browsers). It can also be quite easily faked.

Comment: oh, ty, was open it directly and read it before, was think it just display the current url but after go to google and go to the page to read it again it display google.com... so i know why XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL. If users had click on a bookmark or directly visit your site by typing the URL in the navigation bar, `http_referer` will be empty.

You can analyse these variable by using : [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://username:password@afterclicked.url:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

    echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Output will be : `afterclicked.url`

In your case, use this :

```
<?php
    echo parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

[Here is a sandbox to test it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c7a09ae3d7d8fa852b275e28f978713fa94fcac)

Be careful, some browsers don't provide the `HTTP_REFERER` to respect user's privacy.

Comment: Was solved it anyway, but comeback and accept this as answer to help future visitor.
edit: put in php tester and the first think u give don't work some how, image: http://i.imgur.com/90Loh8N.png
<br>
and there is 1 residual right bracket after PHP_URL_HOST

Comment: Oh yes ! I missspelled the `$url variable`. It is corrected.

Comment: lmao was forgot to accept as answer, just realize it after 2 months.